# A mistake on computing $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to find $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}$. This was my attempt, which is wrong and I cannot find where exactly is the mistake.

First I write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x}-\frac{1}{x}$, therefore $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}=\int \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x}dx-\log\left (x\right )$, so I only have to deal with $\int \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x}dx$.

Setting $u=\sqrt{x+1}$, we obtain $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}dx$, therefore $dx=2udu$ and $x=u^2-1$, so

$\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x}dx=\int\frac{2u^2}{u^2-1}du=\int \left(2+\frac{2}{u^2-1}\right)du=2\sqrt{x+1}+\int \left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)du=$

$=2\sqrt{x+1}+\log \left (\sqrt{x+1}-1\right )-\log \left (\sqrt{x+1}+1\right )=2\sqrt{x+1}+\log\left ( \frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1} \right )$

But then $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}=2\sqrt{x+1}+\log\left ( \frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1} \right )-\log\left (x\right )=2\sqrt{x+1}+\log\left ( \frac{x+2-2\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2} \right )$, which is not what I am supposed to obtain. The actual answer is $2\sqrt{x+1}-2\log\left ( 1+\sqrt{x+1} \right )$.

Where is my mistake?

(I already know a correct way to solve it, I just want to know where I am committing a mistake).

Comment: I believe that you went wrong in your first step. That “simplification” made everything a lot harder. Hint: Start with a u-substitution if u=x+1 .

Comment: The standard  method suggestst to set $u=\sqrt{x+1}$, i.e. $x=u^2-1,\; u\ge 0$, from the very beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you have been right all along!

Notice that
$$\log\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1} - \log x = \log\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)} = \log \frac{1}{(\sqrt{x+1}+1)^2} = -2\log(\sqrt{x+1}+1)$$
by your very first step.

Also, I would suggest that you use $\int\frac{dx}{x} = \log|x|$ (with the absolute value sign, to extend the domain).

What I would also suggest is to use an online function [grapher](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) if you are not sure that your solution is correct. If two functions have identical graphs or if they differ by a constant value, then both are correct solutions of the integral.

Comment: Oh, I see... My answer was correct, but it was not clear why. I wrote $\log\left ( \frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1} \right )=\log\left ( \frac{x+2-2\sqrt{x+1}}{x} \right )$ (i.e., i was rationalizing the denominator), but I should have rationalized the numerator, leading to $\log\left ( \frac{x}{\left ( \sqrt{x+1}+1 \right )^2} \right )$, which gives the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\ln\frac{x+2-2\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}=\ln\frac{(\sqrt{x+1}-1)^2}{x^2}=2\ln\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}$$
if we further simplify,
$$2\ln(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1})
=2\ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}=-2\ln(\sqrt{x+1}+1)$$
You did nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
\frac{x+2-2\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}
=\frac
{(x+2)^2-4(x+1)}
{x+2+2\sqrt{x+1}}
\cdot\frac 1{x^2}\ ,
$$
and this has nothing to do with
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1} \cdot \frac 1x
=
\frac{(\sqrt{x+1}-1)(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}{(\sqrt{x+1}+1)(\sqrt{x+1}+1)} \cdot \frac 1x
=
\frac 1{(\sqrt{x+1}+1)^2}\ ,
$$
which leads to the solution. So the last step is the bad one.

Answer (score 1):

You're fine.

$$\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}\right) -\log x $$

$$= \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}\right) -\log x $$

$$=\log\left( \frac{x}{ (\sqrt{x+1}+1)^2}\right) -\log x$$

$$=\log x -2\log(\sqrt{x+1}+1)- \log x$$

$$=-2\log(\sqrt{x+1}+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

No mistake! $log((\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x})^2)=-2log(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1})=-2log(\frac{x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}{(\sqrt{x+1}-1)(\sqrt{x+1}+1)})=-2log\frac{x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}{x}$